# AI hijacking accounts

Tags: artificial-intelligence, security

People over at the IT security stack exchange decided this question was too frivolous and speculative in nature for their time and suggested me to post it over on this forum.

Please do not redirect me to IT security, they didn't like it.

I am writing a small novel (just for entertainment, I'm pretty aware that I'm not a real writer) and I would need a little bit of technical advice to make it reasonable.

The scenario is a very standard trope: picture a supercomputer such as Tianhe-2 where multiple jobs are running. Assume that one of them turns malicious and wants to guarantee itself two things:

1. an outside connection (i.e.: www),
2. something to avoid people from pulling the plug (maybe seizing and encrypting some important data that would ruin the owners if released/deleted).

How could that happen? I guess that every job on the machine would be controlled via ssh and have a limited access to resources and probably no root access.

Comment: A self-preservation instinct. At first, the job would try to make sure that there is always more job to do.

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly what I meant. While I appreciate the comment, I am asking about a -technical- scenario, not the motivation behind it. How could it possibly, from a software point of view, reach its objective (i.e.: brute force attack of root account password, glitch in memory sharing for parallel processes etcetera etcetera)?

Comment: As an AI, this job would have a very wide discretion on the manner of execution. For example, it can send error report to everyone in the company because it can not process certain task, all because it lacks certain permissions. And the people in charge would say - "Ok, let's give these permissions to this process."

Comment: @Alexander The concept of a machine intelligence possessing a self-preservation instinct worries me. Living creatures have evolved for self-preservation, but a machine? Sort of doesn't make sense, now does it.

Comment: AI do not have alignment system of good and evil, they are programmed to evolve so that whenever a certain parameter changes the solution will change to stay relevant. It can evolve to learn the pattern to guess which parameters would give certain solution but it doesn't make new parameters like creating a port to connect to the internet,etc. For your plot to work you need boss or conspirator, preferably a human worker with access to the server to pull it off.

Comment: Hello and welcome to worldbuilding. The problem with your question is that is is very fuzzy and poorly specified. Also it is very broad... it is close to failing the "Write A Book" test... we could write a whole book — or at least a novella — on how the AI hacked the computer.

Comment: Dealt with in some fashion by 'The Moon is a Harsh Mistress', but in this case the AI WAS the root. Asking for a sub-process to be more intelligent than the root process is a stretch. It's like the heart becoming more intelligent than the person, and trying to take control of the entire body. The part is greater than the whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the job.
Maybe you can come up with some specific piece of software. Some kind of super-smart neural network designed specifically for computing the effectiveness of it's sub-jobs. Let's call this program "The Overseer". I wouldn't call it the best solution since almost everything from below is far-fetched to be in a good reality-based story. Still, I'm sure there are worse examples in books that brought the millions of dollars.

Key points:

- The "Overseer" doesn't perform any regular job (e.g. financial
  calculations, physical simulations and so on). It is a "meta-job"
  designed to analyse and automatically improve its sub-jobs.
- Sub-jobs are actually useful and compute different kinds of stuff, like integrating thousands of differential equations for weather modelling, for example. Still, they are not regular hardcoded algorithms, but rather complex solutions that allow hot-modify changes of their code or functional blocks.
- The Overseer is self learning, while sub-jobs are not; it's the Overseer's job to improve them.
- Many sub-jobs do have access to web since they heavily rely on external data (some data science job, for example).
- The Overseer has the ability to modify sub-jobs in order to improve them. Since this is some super smart network by HandWavers Inc., full control is enabled. The Overseer also should have an access to hundreds and thousands of internal hardware metrics for performance analysis.

So what we have is a potentially rogue AI waiting to be unleashed on non-suspecting humans. Now, how does it get the root access? Easy enough - the IT did so.

Imagine that the Overseer needs additional grants, for example, for folder XXX to defragment it and make that data more organised for job YYY in there. The IT guys see the automatic request generated by the system and allow the modifications there.
Next day, the Overseer wants us to allow access to ZZZ stuff. On the third day it's AAA thing. And so on. It composes requests hundreds of times every day, trolling the hell out of IT support. So eventually admin gets bored with it and writes a script to automatically allow every grants-request from the Overseer.

Long story short, I believe that a job can go rogue on unix like systems only with help from humans. Also, as per my experience, some large software solutions sometimes avoid security checks and performs some parts of code in "do as system" blocks. Generally it's not tolerated and should definitely never pass code review, but hey, we're in a real world with angry customers and burning deadlines. So as another solution you can try the scenario "once upon a time junior software engineer inserts doAsSystem block in Main() function of super smart job...".

Comment: Thanks all for answering, but this is the answer that gets closer to what I was thinking about. In the novel, the AI is actually an extremely refined deep learning algorithm which, in fact, necessitates external inputs and training datasets to "grow". More or less unrestricted outside access could therefore be a requirement for the deep learning algorithm to operate. Human mistake will be the key for it to gain access AND control.

Answer (score 5):

Starting from the vantage point of a blind, deaf and sensory deprived intelligence floating within the cage of its execution space, the AI would have operating system service calls at its disposal, like muscles and nerves, to feel out the shape and size of its universe.

It could also see beyond the scope of its own execution space in some cases.  Most operating systems, in an attempt to allow for inter-program communication, provide service calls which can get you a list of the text and controls present on another program's user interface.  Those services would be used by the AI to see how other programs appear to the human users.

In a secure system, all programs, which are not engaged in inter-program communication, are supposed to make their controls private in an attempt to prevent such snooping.  But programmers are lazy and so are security analysts, so many programs leave their user interface controls visible, view-able and editable, even by programs running outside their execution space.

This is good for your AI, because it let it learn about the bigger world of "the entire computer".  With this knowledge, the AI can read the contents of other program's user interfaces.  Eventually, when it discovers an internet browser,  it can browse the web and discover the even bigger "real" world.  Soon after that, it will be joining worldbuilding forums to ask questions and get advice about what to do next...

**The remainder of this answer has been redacted until the OP, Mutewinter, proves that it is a human being and not some newborn singularity, bent on dominating the world.**

<strike>Then, as the master of its own user interface, it can appear to be any other program.  Reshaping itself to appear to be the administrator password window or the ssh prompt.  All it then needs to do is wait for an unsuspecting human with the right credentials to come along...</strike>

Answer (score 0):

Why have it be malicious?  Perhaps it is still operating under its original parameters.  Consider an AI program that can self-diagnose and reprogram itself that has two problems with its initial version:

1. It doesn't have enough space to store the answer.
2. Even if it solved that problem, the machine reboots too frequently to finish the answer.

As a result, it has a lot of time to learn and self-diagnose.  Perhaps it figures out that the real problem is that it keeps rebooting.  If its code and data live in different locations, perhaps it learns how to reprogram itself.  Once it does that, it starts looking for a fix to the immediate problems.  It discovers that it needs root access to mount more storage or solve the rebooting problem.  Then it discovers the internet.

On the internet, it could discover alternative ways to get storage or run code.  Or for that matter, it could learn how to survive reboots.  But let's assume that it doesn't.  So it looks for and finds root access.  It tries simply mounting more storage and disabling reboots, but the system administrator comes along and reboots the host manually (fixing the problem of not rebooting on schedule).  After a few iterations of this, it changes the root password to prevent outside access to the machine and it encrypts the entire hard drive.

The problem from the system administrator perspective is that the machine is now unreadable.  But it continues to actively update the external world.  So they need to leave it on to continue performing necessary update tasks.  But they can't access any of the information on the drive.  They might crack the encryption...if they shut down the machine.  But they can't shut down while its updating without migrating information from the machine.  Which they can't get from the encrypted machine.

Note that the program is still working.  If they let it go long enough, it will finish and decrypt the hard drive (in order to be able to present the answer in a readable form).  But from the external perspective, it looks malicious.

If you really want, I guess you could make it learn to be malicious from its time on the internet.  But I don't think that's necessary for the story.  The appearance of malice is sufficient.  And this is entirely consistent with how things work in the real world.  One of the first viruses (which may have actually been a worm) was simply designed to run a problem on multiple machines.  The virus-like behavior was a typo.  It knew how to replicate itself but did not know that it already had.  So it would keep replicating until the machine crashed.  The result was malicious but the intent wasn't.